# Pylint (or other solution) and catching dictionary KeyErrors

Tags: python, pylint

Is there a way to use Pylint to check for dictionary `KeyError`s? If not, what are the best alternatives? I have started writing my own solution, which combines Pylint and some custom checkers, but it's started going down the rabbit hole with the degree of complexity required.

I'm not looking for `try`/`except`, I need to check for errors before the program is run.

[EDIT] Some Context

This is for an industrial automation project where we have developed a large (mainly C++, ~1M LOC) distributed equipment control system which aims to autonomously control manufacturing processes. This equipment control system has many responsibilities but not the actual process control logic. This is reserved for a python sub-module. The reason being is that it is typically automation engineers who develop this logic who, by virtue of their job, are not SW devs. They have a good understanding of high-level programming/scripting languages e.g. matlab, VBA, python etc. but are not the most familiar with the more ardous low level concepts e.g. memory management etc. Python allows for a more rapid and low risk approach to developing manufacturing equipment controllers on a day-to-day basis with the main C++ control system managing the more complex requirements of these systems.

I have developed a python "wrapper" which acts as an interface to the main C++ project via websockets which is responsible for the main functionality e.g. main-loop, websockets, error handling etc. etc. This "wrapper" imports some modules which are written by the engineers. These modules are essentially a series of factory functions which the main wrapper provides a dict to which contains all the variables the engineers have at their disposal.

Now, the modules the engineers develop can only be tested with live manufacturing processes, if something goes wrong, its a big deal. A very big deal. Hence, I need someway to preempt any potential error which could cause the controller to fail.

While I appreciate pylint is more widely used as a linter i.e. styling, as it compiles, it does catch a lot of syntactic errors which could cause a failure. There are obviously a lot of other potential issues and so I am not hoping to build something that will catch all errors but I would like it to go a lot of the way.

As mentioned, I have started writing my own checker which is pretty basic. Its a combination of parsing the file for some expressions, and then using a combination of `eval` and `exec`. It works pretty well but the issue is identifying the expressions. There are simply too many use cases and I was really hoping for a quick win. Any help appreciated.

Comment: A `KeyError` isn't a style problem, or something that can be found through static analysis more generally. If you need to always guarantee no error is thrown, use `d.get(key)` rather than `d[key]`. But some context might help with further guidance. *"I need to check for errors before the program is run"* - why? And if so, is Python the right language for the task?

Comment: Checking such error without running is theoretically impossible. You can solve halting problem with such solver.

Comment: Thanks lads. @jonsharpe, I have edited my post with some more context. Also, python may not be the best language but its what is already implemented and I am looking for a quick win. If you have some other suggestions, I'm happy to listen.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be more simple than I thought:

As I was wrapping the modules I want to check for `KeyErrors`, and passing the dicts as arguments to the modules, I knew exactly the name of the dicts which would be offending and had them within scope. I therefore was able to use a simple file parser which used a combination of regex (`re.findall('dict_name(.*])', string)`) to find matches and then `EVAL` to test the keys. I first used pylint to check for standard syntactic errors (and styling etc) and then run my custom dict checker and add the output to the same format as pylints.